# Removing RapidXML newlines & whitespace in output

Tags: xml, rapidxml

How can I prevent RapidXML from adding tabs and newlines between element tags when calling the print(...) function to output XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with the `print_no_indenting` flag:

```
char *end = print(buffer, _doc, rapidxml::print_no_indenting);
*end = 0;
```

or:

```
string s;
print(back_inserter(s), _doc, rapidxml::print_no_indenting);
```